# Unwanted install with apt-get remove

Tags: apt

When I run

`sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk-headless`

The application informs me that it wants to install some other packages or the form `oracle-11-*` etc.

But I just want to free space on my HD so I just would like to **remove-only**.

Is there a command for that?

Console output as suggested by the comments:

```
pi@RevPi35686:~ $ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  oracle-java7-jdk
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java7-jdk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 4 to remove and 158 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

Comment: It is unclear. Please post the full output.

Comment: Unclear and very likely inaccurate. That would be a first if true.

Comment: It happens. If you have a package apt-marked "manual" , and it has dependencies that require Java, then if you uninstall Java-A, the system will try to install Java-B so it still provides Java.

Comment: sorry for not posting the screen capture yet (the problem occurred on the machine of my colleague). so I will look for ways to remove the "manual" mark. (Again, the motivation is just to free space on the HD and "not to not break" the functionality.) Thanks!!!

Comment: console output was added.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you are using? `lsb_release -r`

Answer (score 1):

To get more space in /var/cache/apt/archives/ run `sudo apt-get clean`.

Apparently you have some PPA added offering Oracle Java as alternative Java engine; run `apt-cache rdepends --important --recurse --installed openjdk-8-jre-headless` to find out what is the reserve dependency. If there is none such dependency, you could try `--no-install-recommends` with `apt-get purge`. If there is a dependency, you could remove that, or disable the PPA offering Oracle Java.

Using `sudo apt-get autoremove` will remove unneeded dependencies, too.

Comment: thank you for the reply! we will try this solution asap.